# Sequelize-cli doesn't do anything

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use sequelize and sequelize-cli to create database schema changes (MSSQL) by using the migration mechanism. But nothing is happening - it looks like it does not find any migration files in the migration folder.

I did the following in a new folder to create a test project:

```
npm init
[ added relevant packages: sequelize, sequelize-cli, tedious ]
sequelize init
[ here I added the connection information, all to a blank database on Azure SQL ]
sequelize init:models
sequelize init:migrations
sequelize migration:create
```

I added the following to the created migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
return queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
},
down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
}
};
```

which is basically just according to the template created by the last sequelize command.

Now I would expect a new table to be created when I run the migrate command:

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

But all I get is this:

```
Sequelize [Node: 0.12.2, CLI: 1.7.4, ORM: 3.5.1]
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
Using gulpfile /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/gulpfile.js
Finished 'db:migrate' after 161 ms
```

which means it did not find any migration files. No table has appeared in the database and no sequelizeMeta table was created.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a .sequelizerc file in the root directory to point it to the correct migrations folder:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('path/to/folder', 'config/config.json'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('path/to/folder', 'migrations'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('path/to/folder, 'models')
}
```

Run `sequelize init` after creating file